# Is it possible to supplement Naive Bayes text classification algorithm with author information?

Tags: text, machine-learning, nlp, classification, bayesian

I am working on a text classification project where I am trying to assign topic classifications to speeches from the Congressional Record.

Using topic codes from the Congressional Bills Project (http://congressionalbills.org/), I've tagged speeches that mention a specific bill as belonging to the topic of the bill. I'm using this as my "training set" for the model.

I have a "vanilla" Naive Bayes classifier working well-enough, but I keep feeling like I could get better accuracy out of the algorithm by incorporating information about the member of Congress who is making the speech (e.g. certain members are much more likely to talk about Foreign Policy than others).

One possibility would be to replace the prior in the NB classifier (usually defined as the proportion of documents in the training set that have the given classification) with speaker's observed prior speeches.

Is this worth pursuing? Are there existing approaches that have followed this same kind of logic? I'm a little bit familiar with the "author-topic models" that come out of Latent Dirichlet Allocation models, but I like the simplicity of the NB model.

Comment: From the viewpoint of using machine learning to solve your problem, you can certainly add 'author' as another feature in your feature vector. Also, you wrote that you want to 'replace the prior', which implies that you're implementing the NB algorithm yourself; why would you want do that? Just use an off-the-shelf package. Regardless, the prior probability Pr(Class) is exactly for the classes themselves and not for the features. If you add 'author' as a feature, you should be modifying the likelihood product computation, not the prior.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback -- my one concern with using an "off-the-shelf" package has to do with the construction of my training set. Because I rely on mentions of bills, I'm worried that the proportion of speeches that mention a specific bill (say 10% of the total number of speeches) is not representative of all speeches made. If, for example, there are proportionally more defense bills mentioned in speeches in a given congress, but legislators make lots of floor speeches about abortion (with no associated bill), wouldn't that have the potential to screw up the classifier?

Comment: Class imbalance in the training certainly affects the prior probabilities, but you should prune the training set rather than change the algorithm. For pruning the training set, see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64163/how-to-deal-with-low-frequency-examples-in-classification/

Comment: Note however that priors in Naive Bayes are almost irrelevant because the likelihood term totally dominates: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1403452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to modify anything, simply add this information to your `Naive Bayes` and it will work just fine.

And as it was previously mentioned in the comment - do not change any priors - prior probability is `P(class)`, this has **nothing** to do with actual features.

Just add to your computations another feature corresponding to the authorship, e.g. "author:AUTHOR" and train Naive Bayes as usual, ie. compute `P(class|author:AUTHOR)` for each `class` and `AUTHOR` and use it later on in your classification process.If your current representation is a bag of words, it is sufficient to add a "artificial" word of form "author:AUTHOR" to it.

One other option  would be to train independent classifier for each AUTHOR, which would capture person-specific type of speech, for example - one uses lots of words "environment" only when talking about "nature", while other simply likes to add this word in each speach "Oh, in our local environment of ...". Independent NBs would capture these kind of phenomena.

Comment: What's is an "NV" (in your last sentence)?

Comment: A typo obviously, should be "NB" (Naive Bayes)

Comment: Your notation p(class|author:AUTHOR) is misleading, it's conditioned on the entire feature vector, which includes the author as well as many other things. That is, p(class|author:AUTHOR,fv).

Comment: No, it is not. Naive Bayes is not storing (as it assumes that features are independent) the probabilities in the form of P(class|word0,word1,..) but instead, P(class|word0), P(class|word1), ... and as such, adding author as another "word" is expressed correctly.

Comment: No, this is incorrect---Naive Bayes as an observation model (the likelihood term) is storing probabilities of the form p(w1|class1), p(w2|class1)...p(w1|class2)...etc. It then requires an application of Bayes theorem to get the conditionals p(class|ws). Feel free to verify with any text book on the subject, or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Probabilistic_model

Comment: I also wanted to add a practical comment---because of the peakiness of the likelihood of the NB model (it's junk as far as actual probabilities are concerned, see the ref in the comment to the question), adding one extra feature to a bag-of-words representation is highly unlikely to change the classification. If the question's author finds this approach to yield no substantive change to the decisions, I can elaborate with an alternative answer (although this one is already accepted)

Comment: It does not matter if it stores p(w|class) or p(class|w), I was only answering your "theorem" that it actually stores p(class|w1,w2,...) which was simply false. And I agree that it has small "strength", for a more "powerfull one" training separate NB was proposed in the second part. You should elaborate with alternative answer, even though this one is accepted, the knowledge is important, not "accept tick".

Comment: @BenAllison - Please do elaborate